# handlebars: how to access an array?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have the following simplified document:

```
{
    channel:'Channelname',
    users: [
        {userId:1},
        {userId:2},
        {userId:3}
    ]
}
```

How can i access the userId's in a `{{#each}}` loop like so:

```
{{#each channels}}
    {{channel}}
    {{#each channels.users}}
        {{userId}} //or {{channels.users.userId}} ?
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The first `{{#each}}` loop prints my channelname as expected, but the second `{{#each}}` loop doesn't print anything.

Regards, Cid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
{{#each channels}}
    {{channel}}
    {{#each users}}
        {{userId}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

When going into an each loop, handlebars will use the key names in the array directly.

Comment: Thank you, it works! The main problem was a second "users"-helper. Now i have my "channel"-list in a subtemplate...

Comment: @net.user Could you please explain your solution further? I'm facing the same problem you had originally, but the solution provided by Akshat isn't working for me.

Comment: jchung could you give a snippet of your code in a question? Basically if its a handlebars block you dont have to use '.' to enter into the array item

Comment: I think he meant he had another helper for users that gave a conflict of some sort

Comment: Right, this is, what i mean.