# Meteor Handlebars: How to access a plain array?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

`var plain_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

How can I show all elements in Meteor Handlebars?

```
{{#each plain_array}}

# What to put here to get the elements?

{{/each}}
```

(This question is similar: [handlebars: how to access an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758793/handlebars-how-to-access-an-array/14758957) but not the same as the other question presumes an array of objects.)

Comment: `{{#each array}}{{this}}{{/each}}`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration).

```
{{#each people}}
  <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```