# How do I return an array/value as a cursor am able to use in my template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, return-value, return-type

I have an helper function that returns an array instead of the conventional db.dbName.find() cursor. How do I code a `return array` so it reflects as a cursor similar to one generated by a `db.dbName.find()` that I can use in template?

Find below my helper function:

```
    var arrayTest = Meteor.call('getUserCategoryArray', function(error, results){
    if(error){
        console.log(error.reason);
    } else {          

     var results1 = results.toString();
     var results2 = results1.split(",");
     alert("Array content: " +results2);
     alert(results2[0]);
     alert(results2[1]);
     alert(results2[2]);

     return results2;

     }
 })
```

To explain part of the code: From the top down: The alerts successfully prints out:

```
Array content: shoes,clothes,watches

shoes

clothes

watches
```

The alert is just to confirm that results2 is a working array. 
Now how do I code the return value/array so that I am able to use it in my template as if it was a cursor returned by a `db.dbName.find()` query?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You can pass an array to the #each handlebar.
Checkout the [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234947/meteor-handlebars-how-to-access-a-plain-array)

Comment: @mutdmour Thanks but am failing to understand how to apply it to my code. I tried this in my template:  `{{#each results2}}
 {{this}}
{{/each}}` which didnt seem to work. I also tried the helper function name which is: allCategorie, so in the template I tried `{{#each allCategories}}
 {{this}}
{{/each}}`. still didnt work. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

your issue isn't about arrays, it's about synchronous vs asynchronous programming. as @mutdmour mentioned, spacebars can handle an array from a helper just fine.

helpers can get called several times as a template is rendered, so it shouldn't do anything async or have any side effects. your helper is making an async call, so that's one issue right off the bat.

the issue you're seeing is that such a call is async, and a helper needs to be sync. so you'll have trouble getting your helper to work as-is.

in many cases, helpers return the contents of, or a cursor to the contents of, a collection. i don't know your app, but is a publish/subscribe with collection contents a better choice here?

if not, and it has to be the results from a method call, then generally i will:

1. make the call in the onCreated()
2. write the results to a reactive var
3. return the reactive var from the helper

e.g.

```
Template.Foo.onCreated(function() {
    let self = this;
    self.clothing = new ReactiveVar();

    Meteor.call('getUserCategoryArray', function(error, results) {
        if (!error) {
            // or whatever you need to do to get the results into an array
            self.clothing.set(results);
        }
    });
});

Template.Foo.helpers({
    clothing() {
        return Template.instance().clothing.get();
    }
});
```